# ASP.net page resize

Tags: asp.net

I have a Div which contains a header and a navigation menu(horizontal) . When the user resizes the page the menu gets distorted and the links mov out of the div. How to limit this such that the menu will remain intact on page resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the size for your div using CSS. If your div has a size assigned in pixel or em, the size of the screen won't matter. Scroll bars will be added by the browser, and your content will not get distorted.

```
#myDiv
{
  width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Yes that was what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

To limit the size of an element you can use the min- and max- prefixes. To set the minimum and maximum size. Combined with the width or height as usual. For example:

```
#content { 
  width: 50%; 
  min-width: 300px; 
  max-width: 1900px; 
}
```

Will never be narrower than 300px or  wider than 1900px, but on a 1280 resolution it will be rendered as 640px.

It is widely supported: http://www.caniuse.com/#search=min-width